# .exe file created with Pyinstaller is showin error input(): lost sys.stdin

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

i am using `pyinstaller` to convert a `.py` file to `.exe` file

my `terminal2.py` file is:

```py
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arg = sys.argv
    name = input("Enter your name..")
    print(f"hello, {name}")
```

then in the terminal in the file directory i run the this: `pyinstaller --onefile -w terminal2.py`

[changes in the directory after the above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFQnF.png)

[error when I run the .exe file inside the dist directroy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa6MI.png)

I have looked for help in google, but in vain.

### What I want to achieve?

***Minimum expectation:*** When I double-click the terminal2.exe file, the cli will open and I will be able to do usual input and output stuff according to my python code. 
***More expectation:*** I can create commands like `pip` that can run globally from any `cmd/terminal`

Comment: What's the `-w`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
pyinstaller --onefile terminal2.py
```

More details :

https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

Comment: it worked for me thanks :)

Comment: @abdou_dev [windows defender](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+10) deletes the `.exe` file every time I create it, can you help me with it

Comment: You may have to create an exclusion for this file, see this https://jackboxgames.happyfox.com/kb/article/28-how-to-whitelist-and-resolve-issues-in-antivirus-software-and-firewalls/  for more details and please accept my answer if you see that what I wrote works for you.

Comment: @abdou_dev [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69613613/17123424) --Can you help me with this. please ??

Comment: @abdou_dev please see this post, if you can help me? [post link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69646142/17123424)

Comment: It also works with me.

Answer (score 2):

#### `RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin`

I was using `--noconsole` parameter as:

```bash
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole ScrCpy_GUI.py
```

This could not take `input()` from the user due to no console.

Try (in your case):

```bash
pyinstaller --onefile terminal2.py
```