# Cannot handle PYWINAUTO related exceptions with `try except` block in Python properly?

Tags: python, pywinauto

**My main goal:** Automating [Zoom](https://www.google.com/search?q=zoom)

my zoomModule.py file is:

```py
import os, pywinauto
from pywinauto import Desktop
from pywinauto import findwindows
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys

# Create a instance of Application()
app = Application(backend="uia")


def get_Zoom_Main_Window():
    """starts and connect to zoom main window"""
    zoom_exe_path = os.path.join(
        os.environ["USERPROFILE"], "AppData", "Roaming", "Zoom", "bin", "Zoom.exe"
    )
    try:
        print("starts and connect to zoom main window")
        start = app.start(
            zoom_exe_path,
            timeout=100,
        )
        print("1. Zoom Started")
        connected = start.connect(title="Zoom", timeout=5)
        print("1. Zoom Connected")
        return connected
    except (
        pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError,
        pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError,
    ) as e:
        print("Err_context before 2nd try: ", e.__context__)
        try:
            print("Second try")
            start = app.start(
                zoom_exe_path,
                timeout=100,
            )
            print("2. Zoom started")
            connected = start.connect(title="Zoom - Not connected", timeout=20)
            print("2. Zoom connected")
            return connected
        except (
            pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError,
            pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError,
        ) as err:
            print(err.__context__)
            print("Unknown Problem; Check internet connection and try again!")


def open_join_meeting_window():
    """opens the Join Meeting Popup Window; returns the Join Meeting Window"""
    zoomMainWin = get_Zoom_Main_Window()
    zoomMainWin["Zoom"].child_window(
        title="Home", control_type="TabItem"
    ).wrapper_object().click_input()
    zoomMainWin["Zoom"].child_window(
        title="Join", control_type="Button"
    ).wrapper_object().click_input()
    try:
        joinMeetingWin = app.connect(title="Join Meeting", timeout=15)
        print("Connected to Join Meeting Window.")
    except (findwindows.ElementNotFoundError, pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError) as e:
        print("Err before joinMeetingWin: ", e)
        pass
        # joinMeetingWin['Join Meeting']


hek = open_join_meeting_window()
print("Haa! out of the function")
```

Terminal, when I run the above file:

```
PS D:\PythonDevelopment\my_CLI_tools> python zoomModule.py
starts and connect to zoom main window
1. Zoom Started
1. Zoom Connected
Err before joinMeetingWin:  
Haa! out of the function
PS D:\PythonDevelopment\my_CLI_tools>
```

See how `e` does not get printed or remain blank after `Err before joinMeetingWin:`  in the `open_join_meeting_window()`.
The same happens for the `try-except` block inside the `get_Zoom_Main_Window()`

I have looked for help in google, but in vain.

### What I want to achieve?

**Minimum expectation:** I can `print()` the errors raised by pywinauto to the console/terminal without crashing my code.
**More expectation:** I can avoid `try-except` blocks in my code if possible. Implement better way of `finding and connecting to the required window`, `getting hold of child_window()` and `switching between open windows`.

My approach may be wrong. In that case please show me the correct procedure.

Comment: @abdou_dev Can you help me with this. please ??

Comment: please someone help!!!

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Can you please help me! I am really stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I have figured out how to `print() the errors raised by pywinauto to the console/terminal without crashing my code` with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992124/17123424).

`open_join_meeting_window` function - **Before** ↓↓↓

```py
# after imports
def open_join_meeting_window():
    """opens the Join Meeting Popup Window; returns the Join Meeting Window"""
    zoomMainWin = get_Zoom_Main_Window()
    zoomMainWin["Zoom"].child_window(
        title="Home", control_type="TabItem"
    ).wrapper_object().click_input()
    zoomMainWin["Zoom"].child_window(
        title="Join", control_type="Button"
    ).wrapper_object().click_input()
    try:
        joinMeetingWin = app.connect(title="Join Meeting", timeout=15)
        print("Connected to Join Meeting Window.")
    except (findwindows.ElementNotFoundError, pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError) as e:
        print("Err before joinMeetingWin: ", e)
        pass
```

`open_join_meeting_window` function - **after modification** ↓↓↓

```py
def open_join_meeting_window():
    """opens the Join Meeting Popup Window; returns the Join Meeting Window"""
    zoomMainWin = get_Zoom_Main_Window()
    zoomMainWin["Zoom"].child_window(
        title="Home", control_type="TabItem"
    ).wrapper_object().click_input()
    zoomMainWin["Zoom"].child_window(
        title="Join", control_type="Button"
    ).wrapper_object().click_input()
    try:
        joinMeetingWin = app.connect(title="Join Meeting", timeout=15)
        print("Connected to Join Meeting Window.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
        if e.__class__.__name__ == "TimeoutError":
            print("[TimeoutError]:- The `Join Meeting Window` is taking longer time to appear.")
    print("Passed the try-except block!!")
        pass
```

New terminal logs↓↓↓

```js
ERROR:root:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RAKTIM BHATTACHARYA.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\RAKTIM BHATTACHARYA.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element  
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'hhh', 'backend': 'uia', 'visible_only': False}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PythonDevelopment\Lake\zoom\getJoinMeetingWindow.py", line 14, in open_join_meeting_window
    joinMeetingWin = app.connect(title="hhh", timeout=6)
  File "C:\Users\RAKTIM BHATTACHARYA.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 990, in connect      
    self.process = timings.wait_until_passes(
  File "C:\Users\RAKTIM BHATTACHARYA.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

[TimeoutError]:- The `Join Meeting Window` is taking longer time to appear.
Passed the try-except block!!
```

First, the traditional traceback is printed. Then the name of the error raised by `pywinauto` is used in the control-flow to decide what to do.

Comment: What's you exactly problem ? do you want to print the exception or to solve the exceptions?

Comment: @abdou_dev solve the exceptions and print them without crashing the program. Please see the **What I want to achieve** part in my question.

Comment: @abdou_dev please see this post, if you can help me? [post link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69646142/17123424)

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
 joinMeetingWin = app.connect(title="Join Meeting", timeout=6)
```

by this :

```
 joinMeetingWin = app.connect(title="Join", timeout=6)
```

Comment: that does not make any difference

Comment: See this : https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/859